# Can someone advise me for css overlapping issue?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs adjacent to each other. The upper one is having a checkbox and a label, and the lower one is having a button. I want to give a height to the upper div. This actually sends the upper div text below the button div.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 termscheck">
<div class="checkbox">
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="" class="regular-checkbox"> <span class="terms-spacer" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas non placerat risus. Fusce ultricies libero at consequat finibus. Sed vitae convallis orci. Phasellus eu elementum tellus, eu rhoncus nunc.</span></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1 submitbtn">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="button" class="form-control emailbtn" value="ABSCHICKEN">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Demo link](http://www.bootply.com/FnDegInpAY)

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle or code snippet out of your code so that we can se the problem in action?

Comment: Could you elaborate with a fiddle ?

Comment: You also need to explain what is happening and what you expect.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/0lSmKTRBKf

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the height to `.termscheck`, it behaves as expected. In the following fiddle I just added

```
.termscheck { 
  height: 100px; 
}
```

to the CSS and it works:

http://www.bootply.com/0lSmKTRBKf

Comment: This is fine but now if you try to add text on the label, then it goes behind the button.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But apart from that, I think you need to change the order between input tag and label tag on the checkbox, like this: http://www.bootply.com/nqVAZrawJJ#